# Remove the first 3 characters in var in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How do I do this? I tried:

```
set /p var=""
set var=%var:~3%
echo %var%
```

For example, if I type "Hello World" it should echo "lo World".

Sorry I was too vague. That code isn't really the code but this is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p file=""
set cnt=0
for /F "delims=" %%j in (%file%.txt) do (
  set /A cnt+=1
  set line!cnt!=%%j
)
set cde=0
:code
set /a cde+=1
set line=!line%cde%!
if %line:~0,9% == err echo.%line:~3%
goto code
```

I was just trying to make it shorter well still showing the error.

Answer (score 9):

I just tried it and it works just as you would expect.  What are you getting?

```
C:\>type test.bat
set /p var=""

set var=%var:~3%

echo %var%
C:\>test

C:\>set /p var=""
Hello World

C:\>set var=lo World

C:\>echo lo World
lo World

C:\>
```

So - it seems like you need possibly two things:
1) Some kind of exit condition from your second loop.  Between the `:code` label and the `goto code` for when the matching condition is hit (i.e., `if %line:~0,3% == err`)
Not knowing what is desired from your code, I would place something like the following

```
if %line:~0,3% == err echo.%line:~3% & pause & exit
```

This will pause and exit when it finds the matching line

2) Some kind of exit condition if you reach the end of the lines and there was no match.  My suspicion is this is what is causing the error you are seeing as your input file probably is not satisfying this condition.

Comment: That wasn't the exact code... It just an example. Hold on I'm gonna try something.

Comment: Here `if %line:~0,3% == err echo.%line:~3%>>"%file%.bat"` this is the part where I'm getting an error.

Comment: I think that you may be running into an error because the code you have  is reading through the contents of your input file line by line and then it is looping through checking for an error.  The problem is that your code never halts.  It keeps looping forever, which is why it is throwing an error - probably something like **#line:~3 was unexpected at this time.**  It is telling you that you are trying to process a line that doesn't exist.  You need an exit condition.  I would like to help but you haven't made it clear what you desire the code to do.

Comment: Great!  @VDgames please don't forget to accept an answer for each question you ask